# Insert array of elements into the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an array of elements:

```
const itemCurrent = document.createElement('div');
const itemNext = document.createElement('div');
```

Ive created an array of them:

```
const itemsAll = [itemCurrent, itemNext];
```

How can I insert all of them into the body of my page?

Comment: You can iterate over array and insert into body.

Comment: [insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement), [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over array and appending each using [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

```
itemsAll.forEach(el => {
  document.body.appendChild(el)
})
```

Comment: This could also be inlined: itemsAll.forEach(el => document.body.appendChild(el));

Comment: The correct answer should be what Redu suggests

Answer (score 11):

You may simply use `.append()` to append multiple DOM nodes all at once as follows;

```js
var divs = Array.from({length:10}) // lets make an array of 10 divs
                .map(function(_,i){
                       var el = document.createElement('div');
                       el.textContent = `I am div # ${i}`;
                       return el;
                     });
document.body.append(...divs);
```

In fact the above snippet has some redundany since `Array.from()` bears built in mapping. So the following rephrased code  would be more reasonable.

```js
var divs = Array.from( {length:10}     // lets make an array of 10 divs
                     , function(_,i){  // and map it accordingly
                          var el = document.createElement('div');
                          el.textContent = `I am div # ${i}`;
                          return el;
                       } 
                     );
document.body.append(...divs);
```

Comment: append is not supported on internet explorer: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_parentnode_append

Comment: You can borrow append method from Element and use apply to increase compatibility `Element.prototype.append.apply(document.body, itemsAll);`

Answer (score 3):

To add the elements to the body, you need to append them to the body of your document. This is done by using the appendChild(element) function :

```
// looping through your array : 
for (let i=0;i<itemsAll.length;i++) {
     // appending your elements to the body :
     document.body.appendChild(itemsAll[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Rajesh I edited my answer and added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

To recollect what others have said:

- in JS, you iterate over an array with `array.forEach` which takes one argument - a function that will be called on all the elements of the array sequentially
- to append (add at the end) an element to the DOM (body of the page) you call `document.body.appendChild` which takes the element to be added as an argument

Code you need then becomes

```
itemsAll.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    document.body.appendChild(element);
})
```

or (using ES6 syntax)

```
itemsAll.forEach(el => document.body.appendChild(el))
```